# Как использовать асинхронные функций python в Colaboratory Google?

Tags: python, asyncio

Изучаю асинхронные функции python с помощью сервиса Colaboratory Google. Прошу помощь сообщества так как функция не запускается. Есть простой пример:

```
import asyncio
import time
async def waiter() -> None:
    await cook('Паста', 8)
    await cook('Салат Цезарь', 3)
    await cook('Отбивные', 16)

async def cook(order, time_to_prepare):
    print(f'Новый заказ: {order}')
    await asyncio.sleep(time_to_prepare)
    print(order, '- готово')

asyncio.run(waiter())
```

При запуске в https://colab.research.google.com/ выдает ошибку:

```
asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
*asyncio.run() не может быть вызван из запущенного цикла событий*
```

При замене "asyncio.run(waiter())" на "await waiter()" тоже возникает ошибка:

```
'await' outside function
```

Суть ошибки в том, что в Colaboratory Google по умолчанию уже запущен цикл событий. Запуск нового цикла событий не помогает так как "не возможно запустить новый цикл пока запущен текущий"

Подскажите пожалуйста как запустить функцию waiter()?

Ссылка на блокнот с скриптом [https://colab.research.google.com...](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1S8sbkImyJKGMCSm9GrKx_SDvDzm1kxTC?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать использовать библиотеку nest_asyncio, добавив две строчки кода:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Тогда ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
import asyncio
import time
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

async def waiter() -> None:
    await cook('Паста', 8)
    await cook('Салат Цезарь', 3)
    await cook('Отбивные', 16)

async def cook(order, time_to_prepare):
    print(f'Новый заказ: {order}')
    await asyncio.sleep(time_to_prepare)
    print(order, '- готово')

asyncio.run(waiter())
```